Atom feed ratelimiting prevents feeds from being used
In a different location, Slate asked me to move this question from Meta Stack Overflow here and elaborate on the details.
The current rate limiting on the network prevents feeds from being useful in all cases. This limiting appears to apply to both locally-hosted feed readers as well as cloud-based services like Feedly that may have a limited number of IP addresses.
In high-traffic sites, such as Stack Overflow, the /feeds/newest would need to be requested at least every 5-10 minutes to capture all newest questions posted on the site.
However, it also appears that the rate limit can be triggered by the number of feeds, as well. Simply subscribing to larger numbers of lower volume feeds can trigger the network-wide request rate limiting.
Cloud-hosted solutions may make requests on behalf of multiple users. I believe that Feedly (since that's the service I use) is designed to request each feed URL once and distribute to users. However, multiple people subscribing to different network feeds can result in the service being temporarily blocked from making requests.
I believe that the best solution would be to remove request limits from feed URLs, but monitor for abuse on a case-by-case basis. It may also be prudent to reduce the amount of data sent in each feed by removing or truncating the body of posts - this would require visiting the site to see the full content but enable people to get notified that there is new content.

It would be really annoying if the feed stopped containing the post body. As an answerer, seeing the feed of questions flow to identify ones you can help with is much easier when integrated into one's normal routines, as compared to having to click through to read every question body.

@AMtwo Normally, I'd agree. However, I've seen mention of some clients having issues with bodies that are too large. There's also the matter of formatting things like code blocks not being well-handled (but perhaps also client-specific). Plus, removing or greatly lowering the rate limit could entice bad actors to use these feeds for other purposes. See all the controls around stopping LLM training on the network data. I'd be in favor of truncating the body to some reasonable number of characters, such as 500 or 750 or 1000, perhaps, if truncation is necessary.

While the company has certainly made "LLM Blocking" a top priority far outranking usability, I think the body length would need to be more like 10,000 for the feature to remain useful.

@AMtwo I looked at the Atom spec, since that's what's used, and it doesn't appear to have a size limit so any issue would be a client-side issue. For me, getting a complete list of updates to the subscribed feeds is the most important thing. This is true regardless of what type of feed I subscribe to. If I can't use the client of my choice to request the feed and not miss a notification of new or revised content, the feed is broken and that needs to be fixed. If I miss new questions to a site or new answers to a question, the purpose of the feed is not being met.

Since my concern is "notification", my specific use case would also be addressed with better email digests. But that has other problems and would almost certainly need a full overhaul of the email system to ensure that all content is delivered.
